# "body is missing" error while body is not missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I've tried to post a question and have filled body, clicked on Submit and get an error:

> body is missing

As you can see body is not missing.

I think it is because of encoding, but here is my screenshot. Actually after deleteng all strange symbols it has posted successfully

[image: bug screenshot]

Comment: I'm thinking that trying to post that as text data is a mistake... could the representative contents perhaps be hosted somewhere?

Comment: Where's the rest of your question? You know, the part where you explain what exactly you're trying to do, what you expect the result to be, and all that jazz. All I see here is a code block. Questions shouldn't start with blocks of code.

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦, I've just cutted of all this symbols, because they are not importaint for my issue, I think. But if you need it I'll create a gist with it

Comment: @Cody Gray, fixed

Comment: For the record, I meant the post you're shown creating in the screenshot. Not this question here.

Comment: Haha :) Going to rewrite it a little. Thaught it is clear from the screenshot

Comment: Should your email be out in the open like that? Consider editing the screenshot.

Comment: @alex, ehmm. I didn't understand, what email? Problem is that SO think that my body is empty, while there is a lot of text

Comment: @fl00r: At the bottom of your screenshot is the Notify field; your email is there, in plain sight, mr. fl00r.

Comment: @fl00r alex meant you better remove it... I've done it for you. Also, when you want to show images don't use `<img>` tag instead click the "Attach image" icon in the editor, click "From the web", put the URL and click "Upload" - this way the image will be uploaded to special account and stay here forever. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I understand about email, but I had left my comp, thank you for editing :)

Comment: Cheers @fl00r also keep in mind about uploading the image instead of direct linking to external image host. :)

Comment: I was getting this error in Internet Explorer 10. Changed the browser and tried in Firefox and I was able to post my answer.